# Secure Management Console JBOSS EAP 7 with IBM LDAP

Tags: jboss

I need to setup JBOSS EAP 7 - IBM LDAP connectivity for securing management console access. I am new to JBOSS. I have installed JBOSS EAP 7 and need the users in LDAP to access JBOSS console.

Please guide me for the entire process and setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is:

[2.4.2. Adding Authentication via LDAP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/index)

what you are looking for?